# container that emits logs from file to fluentd container

Tags: docker, fluentd

I want to bring up a container (very basic) that reads data from a file and emits them to stdout to be picked up by fluentd logdriver (log configuration of the container).

I started with the below service in docker-compose

```
  image: httpd
    ports:
      - "8010:80"
    depends_on:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: 127.0.0.1:24224
        fluentd-async: 'true'
```

when i do a curl http://localhost:8010/ - I can see logs routed to fluentd container. I want to route data from file to stdout->fluentd

Comment: what have you tried so far? what errors have you run into?

Comment: @joshmeranda updated the question with what I have tried so far